# Docker consumer on AWS while using RabbitMQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rabbitmq, worker

I have most of my app designed and deployed. We have gone for `RabbitMQ` over `SQS` for several reasons.

I currently have my consumer running in a `docker` container and would like to deploy this on `AWS`. I am *fairly* familiar with `Elastic Beanstalk` since our web-tier is running there, but it seems all workers deployed this way *have* to use `SQS`?

The other option I am aware of is to use `ECS` for the `docker` component, but I do not want to make the image publicly available and don't have access to a private repository.

Is there some basic functionality I am missing, a document describing how to deploy to `ECS` using a `Dockerfile` and source code locally, or a way of deploying to `EB` using a `Dockerfile` without being locked into SQS?

**edit**

So I have found the note on the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html) for `EB` which says that `Dockerfiles` are not supported when building a multi-container environment and that repositories currently have to be used for that purpose, so `EB` is out for me.